# ValueError: Length of values (999) does not match length of index (1000)

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, binance-api-client

I randomly get this error

ValueError: Length of values (999) does not match length of index (1000)

and it always happens in this function...

```
def rsi_tradingview(period, crypto_coin):

    df = ''

    df = getminutedata(crypto_coin, interval_min, lookback)

    round_rsi: bool = True

    #ohlc = df

    delta = df["Close"].diff()

    up = delta.copy()
    up[up < 0] = 0
    up = pd.Series.ewm(up, alpha=1/period).mean()

    down = delta.copy()
    down[down > 0] = 0
    down *= -1
    down = pd.Series.ewm(down, alpha=1/period).mean()

    rsi = np.where(up == 0, 0, np.where(down == 0, 100, 100 - (100 / (1 + up / down))))

    return np.round(rsi, 2) if round_rsi else rsi
```

The period is 25 and the crypto_coin is one of a list of them...

The loop basically created the result of the RSI and puts it into a dataframe...

It's so random when it falls over. Although usually after I have stopped it half way through a loop...

I guess some variable? has something already in it but ???

Any help would be great!
It is really frustrating!

Thanks

Comment: Please [format](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) your code so that the function block is properly indented

Comment: Yes it is in my code. It must have changed when I pasted it into here!!

Comment: Done!

Will you help me now? :-)

Comment: The dataframe - df - is just OHLC data from Binance...